# Fill in Plots vspan saves as black

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I create the plot I need in julia, but upon saving with `savefig`, the `vspan` fill is printed as black, although it is specified as very light red.

This is what is show in my notebook and I am savign [image]
but when I save it as `pdf`, the red blocks become black imposing over the index I want to track[image]
Surprisingly, this does not happened when I `savefig` as `png`, but I would prefer `pdf` for the manuscript I am writing.

Thanks for tips how to fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in pdf, the borders of the vspans are printed quite thick and black while slim in png. I lazily plotted each vspan of width 1 x-axis-tick, so that is what we see. When I specify correctly the vspan intervals [start, end] it is clear

Current setup `julia` to `1.8.5` and the libraries.

```
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.24.0
⌃ [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.6.12
```

and works correctly straight out of box of course.

Answer (score 0):

For best color for publishing, you want to save the image as CMYK PDF/X color, but Plots does not do this. You can use the free publishing app Scribus (under Linux, OSX, Widows, etc) to do the conversion to PDF/X CMYK from png or jpg though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Do you think it is just an incorrectly printed color? I would expect this would work straight out of the box for Plots or some other backends. I tried `plotlyjs` backend but it messed it up into other colors actually. Strange, I would not expect such issues with something that seems simple.

Comment: No, it's probably that the default pdf maker does not handle color well. That's why Adobe made PDF/X.